# How do I fix it when I enter the name of a new student and select a teacher from the selectbox in the database, besides student id, the teacher's id?

Tags: java, database, spring, jsp, mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables in my workbench. Student, Teacher, Student_teacher
The database saves the names and updates the list of students.

Importing a new teacher is provided by a controller:
https://hastebin.com/ecegalecum.java

The new student controller is the same. However, .jsp would be this:
https://hastebin.com/lucipuxaxi.xml

My question would be the following. How do I fix it when I enter the name of a new student and select a teacher from the selectbox
in the database (Teacher_diamonds), besides student id, the teacher's id? So far I've managed to create a new controller for this.

Student repository:
https://hastebin.com/ejumugikam.css

Student entity:
https://hastebin.com/izomeharur.java

A work with STS, MySQL Workbench.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Are you asking how to persist something to the "student_teacher" table with JPA?

Comment: Yes.


If I enter the student's name and select the name of the teacher, enter the student's id and the teacher's id in the teacher_student table. (There are 2 elements in the table -> teacher_id, student_id)

Comment: So you get some input and create a new Student object with it, you just need to retrieve the teacher from the database based on the teacher id that the user selected, then set the student's teacher variable (the @manytoone that you defined in your student entity) to be the one you retrieved from the database (and finally persist the student object you created)